# Parallel stored procedure execution in Azure SQL

Tags: sql-server, azure, task-parallel-library

Through [SSIS a stored procedure can execute in parallel](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6078/parallel-execution-of-tasks-in-ssis/) with different input parameters.

In Azure SQL is there any way we can execute a stored procedures in parallel? If not can we achieve the same feature through any other Azure services?

Comment: No, SSIS can't execute stored procedures in parallel. That link shows using multiple SSIS tasks to emulate this. This has nothing to do with SQL Server itself and therefore Azure SQL. The Azure equivalent to SSIS is Azure Data Factory which can actually execute SSIS packages. You can use the same trick there, create multiple tasks that will run concurrently

Comment: Thanks for the input. We can invoke SSIS packages from  SQL stored procedure similarly can we invoke Data Factory job or tasks from Azure SQL ?

Answer (score 0):

You can open two query windows(that means two sessions) and in both run SQL stored procedure with different set of parameters as you intended.

Regarding, follow up query you can make REST call to ADF Pipeline from your stored procedure. Below link explains how to do REST call from stored procedure | Calling REST API From SQL Server Stored Procedure | [Docs](https://www.zealousweb.com/calling-rest-api-from-sql-server-stored-procedure/)

Below is the link for ADF REST API Microsoft documentation: V2 REST API Reference | [Azure Datafactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/)